Where/how to increment used storage and verify that my user has purchased enough space to upload files?
My App
So I am building an app with sveltekit and supabase. In my app, the user can purchase storage space. The user can upload image files with uppy and its aws plugin.
In my database I have a table with a "storage_quota" and a "storage_used" column.
My Uppy config
 const client = new S3Client({
    ///client config
  });
  uppy = new Uppy<FileMeta, AwsBody>({
    debug: import.meta.env.DEV,
    autoProceed: true,
    restrictions: {
      maxFileSize: 24999999,
      allowedFileTypes: ['.png'],
    },
  })
    .use(AwsS3, {
      shouldUseMultipart: false,
      async getUploadParameters(file) {
        if (file.name === undefined) throw new Error('File name is undefined');
        const putCommand = new PutObjectCommand({
          Bucket: 'designs',
          Key: `${session.user.id}/${sanitizeAWSObjectKey(file.name)}`,
          ContentType: file.type,
        });
        const signedUrl = await getSignedUrl(client, putCommand);
        return {
          method: 'PUT',
          url: signedUrl,
          fields: {},
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': file.type || 'application/octet-stream',
          },
        };
      },
    })

My Challenge
My current challenge is how and where to increment the storage_used and check if the user has enough storage_quota to upload the next file.
What I have tried
Endpoint to check and increment storage
I asked chatgpt and it told me to create an endpoint that checks if the user has enough storage_quota for the current file, upload it and increment the storage_used.
This would turn uppys getUploadParameter function into this:
async getUploadParameters(file) {
  const response = await fetch('/api/upload-params', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      fileName: file.name,
      fileType: file.type,
      fileSize: file.size,
    }),
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    // Handle error
    throw new Error('Failed to get upload parameters');
  }

  const data = await response.json();
  return {
    method: data.method,
    url: data.url,
    fields: {},
    headers: data.headers,
  };
}

Where upload-params would be the endpoint that verifies the users data.
The problem is that I don't know how this would work with concurrent uploads (atomic updates).
Postgres function and trigger on the storage.objects table
I also tried to use postgres functions and a trigger on the storage.objects table but apparently supabase hasn't decided on how triggers should work internally and its not documented.
Is there a best practice for this?

How are you tracking the storage space?  I don't see that here at all.  If it's a database query, you can do that at the beginning of each download without much impact.  If it's just the filesystem, then you may need to do a periodic scan looking for excess space and mark the record as "temporarily on hold".

I have two columns. "storage_quota" is how much the user has available. "storage_used" is where I want to aggregate the used storage. The aggregation is my main concern at the moment.

If those columns are user, then no aggregation is required, right?  If you bump storage_used at the start of an upload, then the concurrency problem shouldn't be an issue.  At most you'll get one file over the limit, and you can scold them for that by email.

Yes you are right. This is probably the most practicable solution since the files of my users aren't that big anyways. Thanks
